# Fast acces to OneDrive as file system for backups

Tags: windows, backup, onedrive, robocopy, network-drive

I was going to use the [robocopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) utility from Windows 10 to backup some folders to my OneDrive storage as described in this article:

http://www.ytechie.com/2014/11/using-unlimited-onedrive-space-for-backups/

I mapped my OneDrive as a network drive as suggested in the article and launched robocopy to create a mirror of a folder with 100 files with total size about 100Kb, but it worked so long - 22 minutes!

Apparently, the built-in OneDrive client works much faster. I did CTRL+C/CTRL+V for the same dir into my OneDrive folder in the Windows Explorer, and it synchronized the stuff in less than 1 minute! Is there a way to access OneDrive as file system with the same speed?

Comment: Just create a network drive that points to the OneDrive folder.  By doing this you silently use the OneDrive client's capabilities.

Comment: @Ramhound, do you mean the local OneDrive folder? I do not understand...